# How to extract a specific column from a list of data frames into a new list of data frames?

Tags: r

How do I extract the second column of each data frame in this list, and store it as another new list of single column data frames? Leaving it as a data frame is very important in the future use of this list.

```
c1 <- runif(10, 0, 10)
c2 <- runif(10, 0, 10)
c3 <- runif(10, 0, 10)
c4 <- runif(10, 0, 10)
c5 <- runif(12, 0, 10)
c6 <- runif(12, 0, 10)
c7 <- runif(12, 0, 10)
c8 <- runif(12, 0, 10)


df1 <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3, c4)
df2 <- data.frame(c5, c6, c7, c8)

list <- list(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
lapply(list, "[", 2)
```